# Joining lookahead regular expressions and keep (all) delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Right now my regular expression go through the string and splits it by occurences of `/`, keeping the slash in the array.

```
var str = 'File/path/to/a/file.js';
let delim = /[^\/]+\/?|\//g; 
var tokens = str.match(delim);
// ["File/","path/","to/","a/","file.js"]
```

As an exercise, I would like to also split by `.`, `?` and `!`. How could I accomplish this without making things too messy? I'm a beginner, so I would ideally like to not have one massive regular expression string. Ideally, I would create an array of regular expressions (with each element of the array handling one delimiter). I have tried to do this but failed.

Comment: You can use: `let arr = str.match(/[^\/.?!]+(?:[\/.?!]|$)/g);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character class to include all the delimiters you have after you match 1+ characters that match anything except those delimiters in a negated character class:

```js
var str = 'File/path/to/a/file.js';
let arr = str.match(/[^\/.?!]+(?:[\/.?!]|$)/g);

console.log(arr);
```